# Battle.net app is stuck at "Loading account information" Linux

Tags: technical-issues, battle.net, linux, wine

I was fixing another bug at baatle.net now it is done after a few days but this got at the foreground now -.- . So I start the battle.net application I enter my details and then the games tab stays on "Loading account information" for a very long time. Options are working nice, the other tab with the news is working smooth also, but this does not.. At the end of this 1-hour waiting I get a message which says:

```
"Oops, something crashed *blah blah blah*"
```

And redirect me to a blizzard help page. The summary was a problem with communicating the update manager/agent.

Also I am running it on Linux via PlayOnLinux.

What I have tried:

1. Closing battle.net app and starting it again.
2. Restarting the whole system and running it.
3. Launching it with Wine directly (gives me another error there - Can not reach the update manager at all).
4. Creating a shortcut and launching it from there.

If someone has any ideas it would be great.

Thank to everyone who loss their time here! {:

Edit:
I waited it to the end now and this is the actual message:

```
Oops! An error occurred while loading game information:
Whoops! Looks like something broke (or crashed). Please try restarting
the Battle.net desktop app and/or your computer. More help: 'Here they give link to this - https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/cannot-communicate-with-battlenet-update-agent'
```

Comment: You might want to try the [Unix&Linux.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com/), this looks more like an emulation problem. The software might just not be compatible with your emulator natively, and finding a workaround for that is not our area of expertise, but theirs. On an unrelated note, have you tried emulating OSX instead of Windows? Maybe the Mac client would work.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with you, Blizzard EU is having problems with battle net right now. And they are saying they're working on a fix.

Comment: Ummm, it happened a few hours before they alerted that, so I am not quite sure.

Comment: Same for me, of course it happens before they alert it, because they don't know about the problem until it happens to a large amount of players!

Comment: But you have the exact same problem?

Comment: I've had it twice in the past 2 days, always passing after 30min-2 hours

Comment: But mine is not fixing at all.. ;{